# How to mock up a method whose name is "method"?

Tags: phpunit

```
class Foo {
  public function method() {

  }
  public function bar() {

  }
}
```

If I have a class `Foo`, I can change `bar`'s behaviour using below syntax.

```
$stub = $this->createMock(Foo::class);

$stub->expects($this->any())
    ->method('bar')
    ->willReturn('baz');
```

> Limitation: Methods named "method" The example shown above only works
>   when the original class does not declare a method named "method". If
>   the original class does declare a method named "method" then
>   $stub->expects($this->any())->method('doSomething')->willReturn('foo');
>   has to be used.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs

---

But my question is, how can I change `Foo::method()`'s behaviour in PHPUnit? Is it possible?

Comment: PHPUnit is open source, therefore it is possible - you will have to fork it and make the changes yourself. I suspect this is not your question though, would you care to narrow the scope of your question?

Comment: @Dezza I mean, how can I change`Foo::method`'s behaviour using PHPUnit? Does PHPUnit provide such a way at present?

Comment: Then do as you mentioned in your question `$stub->expects($this->any())->method('method')->willReturn('foo')`

Comment: The "example shown" that it refers to does not have the `expects()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:
Tested with PHP 7.0.9/PHPUnit 4.8.27

```
public function testMethod()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock(Foo::class);

    $stub->expects($this->once())
        ->method('method')
        ->willReturn('works!');

    $this->assertEquals('works!', $stub->method('method'));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Tested with PHP 7.0.9/PHPUnit 5.6.2 Also:

```
public function testMethodWithDeprecatedGetMock()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock(Foo::class);

    $stub->expects($this->once())
        ->method('method')
        ->willReturn('works!');

    $this->assertEquals('works!', $stub->method('method'));
}

public function testMethodWithCreateMock()
{
    $stub = $this->createMock(Foo::class);

    $stub->expects($this->once())
        ->method('method')
        ->willReturn('works!');

    $this->assertEquals('works!', $stub->method('method'));
}
```

Show only a deprecation warning for the first method but test pass successfully.

Comment: My environment is PHP 7.0.12/PHPUnit 5.6.22. `getMock()` is deprecated so I'm using `createMock()` instead. And it doesn't work... I'll look into it.

Comment: I will check with your env

Comment: I confirmed your second method works properly in a simple test. Maybe some other factors caused the problem. Thanks.